# Using CFUUIDRefs as a Dictionary's keys

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsdictionary

I have a bunch of devices.
They each have a UUID that distinguishes them from each other.
Logically, this is the natural thing to key them by in a dictionary tracking them all, then.

However, the [device UUID] method passes back a CFUUIDRef.

First off, this isn't an object.
But hey, we can fix that.
[device_dictionary setObject:device for Key(__bridge id)[device uuid]];

No, wait, that's not a valid key: It doesn't implement the <NSCopying> protocol.

What's more, since I'm casting these CFUUIDRefs into objects on the fly, will the dictionary even realize when it's been passed the same CFUUIDRef twice? Or will the new object created on the fly by the cast not register as the same object?

Care to help me brainstorm on this? How would you key a dictionary with UUIDs, when they were available as non-objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution would be to convert the returned `CFUUIDRef` into a string for use as the key in the dictionary.

You can convert the `CFUUIDRef` to a `CFStringRef` using `CFUUIDCreateString()` as follows:

```
CFStringRef uuidString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, [device uuid]);
```

You can then use toll-free bridging to convert the `CFStringRef` to an `NSString` for use in an `NSDictionary`.

If you need to convert the string representation of the UUID back to a `CFUUIDRef` you can use `CFUUIDCreateFromString()` as follows:

```
CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreateFromString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidString);
```

There is also a wrapper for `CFUUIDRef` which implements `NSCoding` which can be found at https://gist.github.com/294023. However, this doesn't appear to be ARC compatible.

Answer (score 1):

`CFUUIDRef` is a `CFType`, and you can use any `CFType` as keys in a `CFDictionary`:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef d = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(
  kCFAllocatorDefault, 
  0, 
  &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, 
  &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFUUIDRef u1 = CFUUIDCreateFromString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067"));
CFUUIDRef u2 = CFUUIDCreateFromString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067"));

CFDictionarySetValue(d, u1, CFSTR("fnord"));

CFShow(CFDictionaryGetValue(d, u2)); // prints "fnord"
```

Unfortunately toll-free bridging doesn't work properly in this case, as `-copy` will be called on the key in `NSMutableDictionary`'s `-setObject:forKey:` *before* the custom callbacks (see http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/163407-using-nsimages-as-keys-to-dictionary.html#163439) resulting in a crash.  In any case, it is trivial to use `CFDictionary` in lieu of `NSDictionary`.

Another option is `NSMapTable` if you want an Objective-C solution:

```
NSMapTable *t = NSCreateMapTable(NSObjectMapKeyCallBacks, NSObjectMapValueCallBacks, 0);    
NSMapInsert(t, u1, CFSTR("fnord")); 
NSLog(@"%@", NSMapGet(t, u2)); // prints "fnord"
```